# Firebase Cloud Functions multipart/form-data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible for firebase function to receive http request with multipart/form-data content-type?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242340/how-to-upload-a-file-using-express-on-firebase-cloud-functions/47319614#47319614

Answer (score 1):

Yes but Google Cloud Functions doesn't have the middleware for handling those requests built in by default (see the [body-parser docs for more info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)).

I haven't tested it but [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) looks popular.

If you are uploading files however, I'd recommend you write them directly to [Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) instead. With Cloud Storage you'll get niceties afforded by our SDKs, you'll save bandwidth/time (since you'll be uploading it directly to the storage engine), and you get the benefit of our built-in rules engine. From there you could have a `functions.storage.object().onChange(event => {})` listener in Cloud Functions which would trip whenever a new file was successfully uploaded.

Comment: In many cases adding directly to storage from the client code is not feasible.  It is usually preferable to keep all API keys on the server, in this case in a Cloud Function, and to provide an API layer.