# firebase cloud functions https trigger cannot handle multipart post request recently

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, multer

```
const multer = require('multer')
const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.MemoryStorage,
  fileSize: 6 * 1024 * 1024,
  files: 4
})

const app = express()
app.post('/publish', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
  var body = req.body
  console.log(body)  // print ‘{}’ when req is a multipart request
  console.log(req.files.length) // print ‘0’ even thought post data contains file
  …
})


exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Anythings works well until few days ago. All dependencies is newest version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload a file using express on firebase cloud functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242340/how-to-upload-a-file-using-express-on-firebase-cloud-functions)