# Handling multipart/form-data POST with Express in Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, busboy

I've been trying to handle POSTs (multipart/form-data) with a Firebase function and Express but it just doesn't work. Tried this in local server and it works just fine. Everything's the same except it's not contained in a Firebase function.

Besides screwing up the request object it seems it also screws up the way busboy works.

I've tried different solutions presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242340/how-to-perform-an-http-file-upload-using-express-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase) but they just don't work. As one user mentions, the callbacks passed to busboy (to be called when a 'field' is found or when it finishes going through the data) are never called and the function just hangs.

Any ideas?

Here's my function's code for reference:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const getRawBody = require('raw-body');
const contentType = require('content-type')
const Busboy = require('busboy');

const app = express();

const logging = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`> request body: ${req.body}`);
  next();
}

const toRawBody = (req, res, next) => {
  const options = {
      length: req.headers['content-length'],
      limit: '1mb',
      encoding: contentType.parse(req).parameters.charset
  };
  getRawBody(req, options)
      .then(rawBody => {
          req.rawBody = rawBody
          next();
      })
      .catch(error => {
          return next(error);
      });
};

const handlePostWithBusboy = (req, res) => {
  const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
  const formData = {};

  busboy.on('field', (fieldname, value) => {
      formData[fieldname] = value;
  });

  busboy.on('finish', () => {
      console.log(`> form data: ${JSON.stringify(formData)}`);
      res.status(200).send(formData);
  });

  busboy.end(req.rawBody);
}

app.post('/', logging, toRawBody, handlePostWithBusboy);

const exchange = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  if (!req.path) {
    req.url = `/${req.url}`
  }
  return app(req, res)
})
module.exports = {
  exchange
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please read the [documentation for handling multipart form uploads](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_multipart_form_uploads).

> ... if you want your Cloud Function to process multipart/form-data, you can use the rawBody property of the request.

Because of the way Cloud Functions [pre-processes some requests](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#parsing_http_requests), you can expect that some Express middleware will not work, and that's what you're running into.

Comment: Doug, check out the answer I added.  This is a frustrating bug I lost a lot of time.

Answer (score 18):

The documentation Doug referred to in his answer is good.  An important caveat though is that `rawBody` does not work in the emulator.  The workaround is to do:

```
if (req.rawBody) {
    busboy.end(req.rawBody);
}
else {
    req.pipe(busboy);
}
```

As described in this issue:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-emulator/issues/161#issuecomment-376563784

Comment: FYI this is now fixed

Answer (score 4):

I've combined the previous two answers into a easy-to-use async function.

```js
const Busboy = require('busboy');
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function extractMultipartFormData(req) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (req.method != 'POST') {
      return reject(405);
    } else {
      const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
      const tmpdir = os.tmpdir();
      const fields = {};
      const fileWrites = [];
      const uploads = {};

      busboy.on('field', (fieldname, val) => (fields[fieldname] = val));

      busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename) => {
        const filepath = path.join(tmpdir, filename);
        const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filepath);

        uploads[fieldname] = filepath;

        file.pipe(writeStream);

        const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          file.on('end', () => {
            writeStream.end();
          });
          writeStream.on('finish', resolve);
          writeStream.on('error', reject);
        });

        fileWrites.push(promise);
      });

      busboy.on('finish', async () => {
        const result = { fields, uploads: {} };

        await Promise.all(fileWrites);

        for (const file in uploads) {
          const filename = uploads[file];

          result.uploads[file] = fs.readFileSync(filename);
          fs.unlinkSync(filename);
        }

        resolve(result);
      });

      busboy.on('error', reject);

      if (req.rawBody) {
        busboy.end(req.rawBody);
      } else {
        req.pipe(busboy);
      }
    }
  });
};
```