# Firebase hosting and cloud functions don't work with formidable: incomingForm is not a constructor

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, formidable

I use `express` to handle post requests and formidable to parse uploaded files:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as formidable from "formidable";
import * as util from "util";
import * as express from "express";

admin.initializeApp();
const app = express();

app.post("/image", (req, res) => {
  const form = new formidable.incomingForm();
  form.parse(req, async function(err, fields, files) {
    res.writeHead(200, { "content-type": "text/plain" });
    res.write("received upload:\n\n");
    res.end(util.inspect({ fields: fields, files: files }));
  });
});

export const api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I already rewrite source and function in firebase.json. I kept getting error `Internal Server Error` when deploying and when serving: `TypeError: formidable.incomingForm is not a constructor` after posting my form.

`formidable` works well with normal node server and Express server on my machine. I already tried firebase node 8 engine beta, used JS instead of TS and still didn't work. How can I make formidable work with Firebase hosting and cloud function? Please help.

Here are my simple client form:

```
<form action="http://myfirebaseserver/image" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="myImage" />
  <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

At the moment I'm trying `busboy` for alternative but still looking for solutions on `formidable`

Comment: Firebase Cloud Function Node.js doesn't have a built-in multipart/form-data parsing library. Formidable does not work due to this reason.
Instead, we can use the 'busboy' library from NPM to parse these requests.
And here is a solution
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#multipart_data Also, see here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48289824/handling-multipart-form-data-post-with-express-in-cloud-functions?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Formidable doesn't work with Cloud Functions](https://github.com/utatti/express-formidable/issues/21), for the same reason that [multer doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242340/how-to-perform-an-http-file-upload-using-express-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase).  Use busboy instead.

Answer (score 4):

[Formidable-serverless](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable-serverless) is a good option. It works with Firebase Cloud Functions.