# Handling multipart/form-data POST with Nest in Cloud Functions - Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, nestjs, firebase-storage, multipartform-data

I have a problem similar to the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48289824/handling-multipart-form-data-post-with-express-in-cloud-functions). However, I was unable to solve it as indicated in that post because it does not work for me (or I don't know what I'm doing wrong) with busboy.

This is my code that runs my Nest application and then embeds it within a firebase function:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { ExpressAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as express from 'express';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as cors from 'cors';
import * as morgan from 'morgan'; // Import morgan middleware

import { config } from 'dotenv';

config();

const server = express();
server.use(cors());
server.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
server.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false, limit: '50mb' }));
server.use(morgan('dev')); // Use morgan middleware with 'dev' format

const createNestServer = async (expressInstance) => {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(
    AppModule,
    new ExpressAdapter(expressInstance),
  );

  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
      forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
    }),
  );

  return app.init();
};

createNestServer(server)
  .then((v) => console.log('Nest Ready'))
  .catch((err) => console.error('Nest broken', err));

// Listen on localhost:3000
if (process.env.DEV == 'nest') {
  server.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on http://localhost:3001');
  });
}

export const api = functions.https.onRequest(server);
```

This is my test file controller:

```
import {
  Body,
  Controller,
  Get,
  HttpException,
  Post,
  Req,
  UploadedFile,
  UseInterceptors,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { FileInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { imageMulterOption } from 'utils/interceptors/image.multerOption';
import { StorageService } from 'infrastructure/storage/storage.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(
    private readonly storageService: StorageService,
  ) {}

  ....

  @Post('file')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', imageMulterOption))
  public async uploadFile(
    @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
    @Req() req: Request,
  ): Promise<string | HttpException> {
    console.log(req.headers);
    return await this.storageService.uploadFile(file);
  }
}
```

When I run an http request with the DEV environment variable set to "nest" using Postman, it allows me to test the Nest core application and the file upload works correctly. However, when DEV is set to "firebase", the firebase emulator runs and I get the following error with the same request:

`{ "statusCode": 400, "message": "Multipart: Unexpected end of form", "error": "Bad Request" }`

I need help with this bug that has been driving me crazy for a while...

This is my http request:

POST /gymbro-27bb2/us-central1/api/file HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5001
Content-Length: 176
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="nest js.png"
Content-Type: image/png

(data)
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

I expect the next response:

"File uploaded"

Answer (score 3):

I worked on a custom Interceptor compatible with Cloud Function, Decorator of nest js and test (supertest)

Require :

- crypto
- bysboy

```js
import {
  BadRequestException,
  CallHandler,
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  NestInterceptor,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import Busboy, { Limits } from 'busboy';
import { randomUUID } from 'crypto';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Readable } from 'stream';

type FileInterceptorOptions = {
  limits?: Limits;
};

@Injectable()
export class FileInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private fieldName: string,
    private maxCount?: number,
    private options: FileInterceptorOptions = {},
  ) {}
  intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler,
  ): Observable<any> | Promise<Observable<any>> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const busboy = Busboy({
        headers: request.headers,
        // 10Mb by default
        limits: this.options.limits ?? { fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10 },
      });
      const fields: {
        [x: string]: string;
      } = {};

      const files: (Partial<Express.Multer.File> & { id?: string })[] = [];
      let count = 0;

      busboy.on(
        'file',
        (
          name: string,
          file: Readable,
          information: { filename: string; encoding: string; mimeType: string },
        ): void => {
          const id = randomUUID();
          if (name !== this.fieldName) {
            file.resume();
            return;
          }

          if (
            typeof this.maxCount !== 'undefined' &&
            count++ >= this.maxCount
          ) {
            file.resume();
            throw new BadRequestException('Too many files...');
          }

          file.on('data', (data: any) => {
            const file = files.find((v) => v.id === id);
            if (file) {
              file.buffer = Buffer.concat([file.buffer, data]);
              file.size = (file.size as number) + data.length;
            } else {
              files.push({
                id,
                fieldname: name,
                originalname: information.filename,
                encoding: information.encoding,
                mimetype: information.mimeType,
                size: data.length,
                buffer: data,
              });
            }
          });
        },
      );

      busboy.on('field', (name, value) => {
        fields[name] = value;
      });

      busboy.on('finish', () => {
        request.body = fields;
        const data = files.map((file) => {
          delete file.id;
          // file.stream = new Readable();
          // file.stream.push(file.buffer);
          return file;
        });

        // Compatibility with Nest.Js Decorator
        if (this.maxCount === 1) request.file = data[0];
        else request.files = data;

        resolve(next.handle());
      });

      busboy.on('error', (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });

      // Cloud environment
      if (request.rawBody) busboy.end(request.rawBody);
      // Standalone or test environment
      else request.pipe(busboy);
    });
  }
}
```

And how to use it :

```js
  @Post('/your-route')
  @UseInterceptors(
    new FileInterceptor('files', 2, {
      limits: {
        // limit to 100Mb
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 100,
      },
    }),
  )
  async uploadFiles(
    @UploadedFiles()
    files: Express.Multer.File[],
  ) {
    console.log(files)
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
```

Validator in the pipe of `UploadedFiles` and `UploadedFile` is working too

Special thanks to this [comment](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy/issues/296#issuecomment-1467129794)

Comment: Thanks brother this helped me a lot, Just a minor thing I had to update the imports like below

`  import { Limits } from 'busboy';
  import * as Busboy from "busboy"`

for some reason default import was not working for me 

P.S for TS please also install types of busboy

Comment: Depends of your ts config if you had set allowSyntheticDefaultImports  to true