# TypeError: next is not a function in multer package

Tags: node.js, firebase, multer

I  happen to be getting this kind of error when i upload the files.
i have been using multer package for long time without any issues.

I happen to be using google cloud storage on node v6.11.4

c

```
onst {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage')
const multer = require('multer');
//configuring the google cloud storage.
 const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: functions.config().project.id
  //keyFilename: "<path to service accounts prviate key JSON>"
 })

 //const bucket = storage.bucket("<Firebase Storage Bucket URL");
  const bucket = storage.bucket(functions.config().bucket.url)
  //multer confguration.. middleware
  const upload = multer({
    storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
    limits:{
      fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024 // no larger than 5mb, you can change as needed.
    }
  })
exports.updateUserRole = functions.https.onRequest(upload.single('license'),(req,res) => {

I expect this file to be uploaded
Actual results
TypeError: next is not a function at multerMiddleware (/user_code/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:18:41) at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9) at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:726:7 at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:709:11
```

Answer (score 0):

[Formidable doesn't work with Cloud Functions](https://github.com/utatti/express-formidable/issues/21), for the [same reason that multer doesn't work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242340/how-to-perform-an-http-file-upload-using-express-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase) 
Use busboy instead.
[How to perform an HTTP file upload using express on Cloud Functions for Firebase (multer, busboy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242340/how-to-perform-an-http-file-upload-using-express-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase)
So this question is somehow related to above issues in the links unless someone objects as per now...