# how to get image uploaded from angular in firebase cloud node function?

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, multer

I am trying to upload an image to firebase firestore , but before that I need to resize the image through cloud functions.

Below is the code I tried with:

**component.html**

```
<input type="file" name="image" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
```

The **component.ts** file

```
handleFileInput(files: FileList){
  console.log("uploaded files.......", typeof files.item(0));

  let postData = new FormData();
  postData.append("image", files.item(0));

  console.log('postData.................', postData);

  this.http.post('https://[.....]/app/resize', postData).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(".........", data);
  });
}
```

And here is my **cloud function**:

```
const upload = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log('upload called...............................');
    const isValid = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
    let error = new Error("Invalid mime type");
    if (isValid) {
      error = null;
    }
    cb(error, "../tmp/");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log('something is here........', file);
    const name = file.originalname
      .toLowerCase()
      .split(" ")
      .join("-");
    const ext = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
    cb(null, name + "-" + Date.now() + "." + ext);
  });
app.post('/resize', multer({ storage: upload }).single("image"), (req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => { });
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
  console.log("##", req.body);
  console.log("##", req.file);
}
```

I am getting `req.body as empty object {} and req.file as undefined`?

I am not able to debug it to understand if the problem is in angular side or on firebase node-express side.

> The postData is formData and its content is not visible in the console of
>   browser.

Could you please guide me to fix this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242340/how-to-perform-an-http-file-upload-using-express-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase