# Firebase Cloud Functions and Busboy not parsing fields or files

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, axios, busboy

I've been doing some experiments with Firebase Cloud Functions and Express, and I am stuck with a problem when I try to process a FormData with Busboy. 
**It seems that I only get one big malformed text field with all the data in it, including also any binary data of files I try to upload (i.e. gibberish ascii characters)**.

I've tried the different solutions found online, even here on SO, and I see that all of them are built around the example provided by Google about Multipart Data:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http

This is my server-side code:

```
// index.js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const Busboy = require('busboy');

app = express();

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  const busboy = new Busboy({
    headers: req.headers,
    limits: {
      // Cloud functions impose this restriction anyway
      fileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024,
    }
  });

  busboy.on('field', (key, value) => {
    console.log(`Busboy field ${key}: ${value}`);
  });

  busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
    console.log(`Busboy file ${fieldname}: ${filename}`);
  });

  busboy.on('finish', () => {
    console.log('Busboy finish');
    return res.send({
      status: 'Success',
      text: 'Great job!'
    });  
  });

  busboy.end(req.rawBody);
});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

And this is the client in Node JS:

```
// index.js
import axios from 'axios';
import FormData from 'form-data';

const ENDPOINT_URL = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;

const postFile = async () => {

    try {
        const form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('userName', 'Fred');
        form_data.append('password', 'Flintstone');
        const response = await axios.post(`${ENDPOINT_URL}/upload`, form_data);
        console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error: ${error}`);
    }
}

postFile();
```

On the client log everything is as expected, and I get the 'Great job' response back. However, this is what I get on the Firebase Cloud Functions log:

```
Busboy field ----------------------------047691570534364316647196
Content-Disposition: form-data; name: "userName"

Fred
----------------------------047691570534364316647196
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

Flintstone
----------------------------047691570534364316647196--
)
```

Note that it's just **a single output line in the log, meaning that Busboy called onField only once**. As said above, if I add to the FormData a file, the output is very messy and I still get only ONE call to onField and none to onFile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigations, I found out that the server is working properly, while on client I need to change this line:

```
const response = await axios.post(`${ENDPOINT_URL}/upload`, form_data);
```

to:

```
const config = { headers: { 'content-type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form_data._boundary}` }};
const response = await axios.post(`${ENDPOINT_URL}/upload`, form_data, config);
```

Apparently, despite what stated in other posts here on SO, not specifying the multipart header doesn't cause it to be determined automatically. 
Note also that if you omit the `boundary` setting, you will get a `Boundary not found` error from Busboy on the server.

Comment: Can anyone confirm this? Although I think this may be because you are using axios while using something like fetch will automatically handle it.

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer have this project available, and can't try to swap axios for fetch. But thinking twice: if that worked, does it mean that fetch is automatically adding the header?

Comment: I don't have ._boundary on formData though. Where you getting that from?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to write `bb.end(req.body)` before `req.pipe(bb)`