# Req.file undefined with express-fileupload and multer packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer, nodemailer

I tried all possible scenarios and I tried with multiple variations and approaches suggested by documentation and by other stackoverflow questions.

Any of them worked -> I keep getting `req.file is: undefined`
Form:

```
<form action="/send" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

        <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Express Setup:

```
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const homeController = require('./controlers/homeController');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');



const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));


app.listen(3000);


/* routes */
app.use(homeController);
```

I have the following code:

```
var multer = require('multer')

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './public/data/uploads',
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

var upload = multer({
    storage: storage
}).single('file');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home')
})


router.post('/send', (req, res) => {

    upload(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);

        console.log('req.file is: ' + req.file);
    });

})
```

I spent 2 days trying to figure this out but I can't see the light at the end of the tunnel, and i just want to get the file from client and send it with nodemailer as attachement later on.

Comment: Can you show how you've setup express? Also does it also fail if you try the upload through curl/postman?

Comment: @eol yes, postman also fails. I added the express setup. Is there any setup we need to do specifically for this? I replicated setup I have seen in tutorials, documentation etc etc and none of it works for me.

Comment: @Paulo When you test with postman, you pass your data including image in `form data` tab?

Comment: @HtetPhyoNaing yes. Is it possible that because I'm using firebase it is blocking the data for some reason? I tried to create a brand new app without putting it in firebase and it works properly, so I am wondering if this is not firebase related.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform an HTTP file upload using express on Cloud Functions for Firebase (multer, busboy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242340/how-to-perform-an-http-file-upload-using-express-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase)

Comment: @eol thank you! It seems I am not alone with this issue. It is good to know it wasn't due to my code. I will give it a try and provide a comment back with the solution that worked for me.

Comment: @eol managed to get solution... I'm so happy - thank you so much for pointing me to this answer.

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Answer obtained based on eMAD suggestion on question [How to perform an HTTP file upload using express on Cloud Functions for Firebase (multer, busboy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242340/how-to-perform-an-http-file-upload-using-express-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase)

Solution below:

- File is saved on the storage location you define in muller.
- req.files is an array with the details of the file/files you upload.

PS: thanks @eol for pointing me in this direction

```
const contactControler = require('../controlers/contactController');
const busboy = require('busboy')
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');
const SIZE_LIMIT = 10 * 1024 * 1024 // 10MB
var stor = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: '../public/cv',
    filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.originalname);
    }
});

const multipartFormDataParser = multer({
    storage: stor,
    // increase size limit if needed
    limits: { fieldSize: SIZE_LIMIT },
    // support firebase cloud functions
    // the multipart form-data request object is pre-processed by the cloud functions
    // currently the `multer` library doesn't natively support this behaviour
    // as such, a custom fork is maintained to enable this by adding `startProcessing`
    // https://github.com/emadalam/multer
    startProcessing(req, busboy) {
        req.rawBody ? busboy.end(req.rawBody) : req.pipe(busboy)
    },
})


router.post('/send', multipartFormDataParser.any(), contactControler.send);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding `upload` in your route as middleware.

```
router.post('/send', upload, (req, res) => { ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work by adding it. I keep receiving that req.file is undefined.