# React: Multer image and data upload with using firebase function, node multer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, multer

Basically I am using firebase function and hosting with node and react. I can upload image courtesy of [How to perform an HTTP file upload using express on Cloud Functions for Firebase (multer, busboy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242340/how-to-perform-an-http-file-upload-using-express-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase)
but how do you upload image and data at the same time?

```
export const addProduct = (product, imageUrl) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fileData = new FormData();
      fileData.append("imageUrl", imageUrl);
      fileData.append("productData", product);
      axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "/api/products/add-product",
        data: fileData,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      });
    });
  };
};
```

NodeJS

```
const router = express.Router();
const Busboy = require("busboy");

router.post("/api/products/add-product", async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    const uploads = {};
    busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
      console.log(
        `File [${fieldname}] filename: ${filename}, encoding: ${encoding}, mimetype: ${mimetype}`
      );
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your client-side code looks OK.
On the server-side you can tell busboy to extract fields as well as files:

```
const fields = {};
const files = [];
const busboy = new Busboy({headers: req.headers});
busboy.on("field", (key, value) => (fields[key] = value));
busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {/*...*/});
busboy.end(req.rawBoy);
```

This way you can access `fields["productData"]` later in your code.

Note that you need to use rawBody to access the unparsed body in Cloud Functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request